# Can you apply for B1/B2 US visa without a trip planned?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, uk-citizens, polish-citizens

I'm a British and Polish citizen living in the UK. Next year I'm visiting a country that disqualifies me from the visa waiver program on my British passport.

My partner is American so we go to the US on a whim sometimes so it would be good to just have a visa in one of my passports incase we need to go quickly. Is it possible to apply for one without actually having a trip planned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specific travel plans are not required. People often apply for visas before they have things settled. In fact, they suggest you don't buy tickets until you know you got the visa.

Comment: Does this apply if you have zero plans or intensions of going soon? Just so I have the visa incase I need to go in a hurry etc. Can you provide some official information, I don't want to apply and get rejected.

Comment: @BritishSam you need to have some intentions to use it before the visa expires. The DS-160 form has the question: *Have you made specific travel plans?* is proof